# Meaning of "life kind of got in the way for a little while"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I asked an online  friend "I haven't see you for  a while".

He replied

> Yeah, life kind of got in the way for a little while.

What doe's it mean? And what's its structure?

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom that means the routine of day-to-day living (things your friend **had** to do) had to take priority over things your friend **wanted** to do.

In this case, it sounds like the demands of day-to-day living (jobs, bills, responsibilities, family, illness and hardships to name a few) had to take priority over socialising with his friends for a while.

Comment: Thanks, however I don't know how that sentence means what you say. Is it grammatical by the way?